# Using Cygwin to generate and link DLL to another project

Tags: c++, dll, cygwin

C++ newbie here, I have this game engine I am making and I would like to export it into `.dll` and use it in a sandbox project. It depends on `GLFW`, `spdlog` and `Vulkan`. I am using `g++` on Windows with `Cygwin`.

Here is a simple version of my project:

```
Sandbox
   |----Sandbox.cpp
Engine
   |----Engine.h
   |----vendor
           |----glfw
           |----spdlog
```

So `Sandbox.cpp` includes `<Engine.h>`, `Engine.h` includes `<GLFW/glfw3.h>`

Here are my commands:

1. First compile from Engine:

   `g++ -std=gnu++11 -I someIncludeDir -c someCPP.cpp -o objectFiles.o`
2. Then build dll:

   `g++ -shared -o objectfiles.o -L./path/to/GLFW/DLL -L"C:\Windows\System32" -lglfw3 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lvulkan-1 cygxxx.dll -Wl,--out-implib,libxxx.dll.a`
3. This will give me a `cygxxx.dll` and `libxxx.dll.a`.
4. I moved these 2 files into Sandbox project.
5. Compile the Sandbox project:

   `g++ -std=gnu++11 -I../Engine/Engine.h someCPP.cpp -c objectfiles.o`

And this is where I got the error saying `<GLFW/glfw3.h>` not found.

My confusion is, I don't want to include `GLFW` or `Vulkan` in my **Sandbox** project, nor do I want to include them in my compiler flag. Is this even possible?

Please help a C++ noob.

Comment: Linker works with .dll.a, but compiler works with *.h.

Comment: @Philippe So what should I do if I don't want to include `glfw.h` directly in my Sandbox? Because my Sandbox does not directly depend on GLFW

Comment: Did you create Engine.h ?

Comment: @Philippe Yes, it's under the Engine folder. Sandbox has no problem finding  `Engine.h`, but since `Engine.h` includes GLFW, compiler starts complaining.

Comment: @Philippe It works if I just include GLFW in my Sandbox compiler flag. But is it possible if I don't want to do that neither? Can I pack entire GLFW plus Engine plus all other dependencies and jam it into Sandbox?

Comment: As you created Engine.h and it includes GLFW/glfw3.h, that means your project depends on GLFW.